# porque me retorna vació una función en POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-13

HE CREADO LA SIGUIENTE FUNCIÓN, LA IDEA ES RECORRER UNA TABLA QUE TIENE LAS FECHAS, CLASIFICADAS EN FESTIVO Y EN NO FESTIVOS, PERO LA FUNCIÓN ME RETORNA UN VACIÓ, EXISTE ALGÚN ERROR ?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getdate() RETURNS SETOF pqr.calendario AS
 $BODY$
  DECLARE  
   count_days integer;  
   r pqr.calendario%rowtype;
  Begin  
    count_days = 0;
     FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pqr.calendario
      WHERE fecha >=  now()
      LOOP 
       count_days = count_days +1; 
          IF count_days = 5 THEN
              RETURN NEXT r;
          END IF;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN;
  END 
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el `IF` está afectando tu resultado, pues solo estas retornando cuando cuando `count_days = 5` , y eso solo se cumpliría una sola vez, creo que debes replantear la lógica de esa función y si no esta retornando puede que no este llegando ni a `5` su valor